# Javascript inside a rails app, delete a cookie after 30 minutes of creation

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript which is creating a cookie, and I would like to automatically delete this cookie after 30 minutes of creation.

```
function getGeoLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
}

function setGeoCookie(position) {
    var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this to work with the following:

```
function setGeoCookie(position) {
    var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
    //declare date and get current date time
    var date = new Date();
    //add 30 minutes to date
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
    //create the expires variable
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    //pass the "date" variable to expires properity
    document.cookie = 'lat_lng'+"="+cookie_val+expires+"; path=/";

}
```